Power BI Line Charts: How to bring lines down to 0 for missing values

I have a line chart in Power BI. As you can probably tell, the first data point has a huge uptick because there are no other data points in between. Is there any way I can bring the line down to only reflect the first data point, then it'll go back to 0 immediately after?
I've tried, as suggested in another question here, the formula
TOTAL = IF(ISBLANK(SUM(Table1[Amount])), 0, SUM(Table1[Amount]))

but it fails to work and push the line down. I believe that's because that data point simply doesn't exist in the original data. How could I get around this? Perhaps, how can I add in data points manually?

This uptick is caused by blank values on the x axis. Try selecting the visual and setting the Month Year to "is not (Blank)".

